# Unable to hide to UINavigationBar properly

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uinavigationbar

Hello guys I hope you are having a good day.

I have been trying to hide `UINavigationBar` that comes with `UINavigationController` for a while now and finally I had some success but the issue is every time I move from the `UINavigationController` to another or exit the app and get back (while the `UINavigationBar` is hidden using my code) weird things happens to the `UINavigationBar` I will demonstrate my code and a GIF from what is happening.

Things mainly happen in

> scrollViewDidScroll

`UIScrollViewDelegate` method
Then when the scroll ends the code in

> scrollViewDidEndDragging

will run

Normal Behavior
[image: behavior]
After returning to the App
[image: after switching views or exiting app]

```
extension GDMainViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {

func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if urlField.isFirstResponder {
        urlField.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    let scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y

    if webScrollLastYAxis == nil {
        webScrollLastYAxis = scrollOffset
    }
}

func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {

    let scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y

    if !decelerate {

        guard let navigationBar = navigationController?.navigationBar else {
            return
        }

        let navOffset = navigationBar.frame.origin.y
        let navViews = navigationBar.subviews[2].subviews


        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            if navOffset < -10 {
                navigationBar.frame.origin.y = self.statusBarFrame
                for view in navViews {
                    view.alpha = 0.0
                }
                self.webScrollIsHidingViews = true
            } else {
                navigationBar.frame.origin.y = 20
                for view in navViews {
                    view.alpha = 1.0
                }
                self.webScrollIsHidingViews = false
            }
        }
    }

    webScrollLastYAxis = scrollOffset
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    guard let navigationBar = navigationController?.navigationBar else {
        return
    }
    guard let oldScrollOffset = webScrollLastYAxis else {
        return
    }
    let scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let navOffset = navigationBar.frame.origin.y
    let navViews = navigationBar.subviews[2].subviews

    if oldScrollOffset > scrollOffset {
        //print("downwards")
        if navOffset < 21 && navOffset >= statusBarFrame {
            if navOffset != 20 {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
                    navigationBar.frame.origin.y += 1
                    for view in navViews {
                        let newAlpha = view.alpha + 0.04
                        if newAlpha > 1 { view.alpha = 1.0
                        } else { view.alpha = newAlpha }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        //print("upwards")
        if scrollOffset > 0 {
            if navOffset < 21 && navOffset >= statusBarFrame {
                if navOffset != statusBarFrame {
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
                        navigationBar.frame.origin.y -= 1
                        for view in navViews {
                            let newAlpha = view.alpha - 0.02
                            if newAlpha < 0 { view.alpha = 0.0
                            } else { view.alpha = newAlpha }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You also want to hide status bar?

Comment: Also check your webView frame, Seems like you are giving some margin

Comment: no I don't want to hide the status bar but I want the UINavigationBar to be viewable after returning to this UINavigationController my problem is when I exit the app (while the UINavigationBar is hidden using my code) and get back in the UINavigationBar returns to its default frame and its contents are hidden

Answer (score 0):

**Might be help this-**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
     searchBar.isHidden = false

}
```

Comment: it seems apple is forcing the navigationbar to appear this code did not work but what I have done is to hide/unhide the bar using my code in viewwillapear now the content appear but the frame is not being set.... I came to this conclusion as I have tried a different browser (firefox) the issue happen if the navigationbar is hidden then you exit the app and get back in, it will set the frame to the original